# How to use GlobalRequestFilters in ServiceStack? It doesn't seem to be fired

Tags: c#, servicestack

I want a customer authentication flow and I just want to decorate the Requests with [Authenticate] to block some of the secured ones.

To check if they are authenticated, I wanna basically just lookup my own cache to see if they are logged in (using the auth token in the http headers).

I have for the last number of hours tried to find out how to do it in ServiceStack, but failed.

On the one hand, I tried to use a "Plugin" and implement a custom CredentialsAuthProvider, but the "TryAuthenticate" nor the "Authenticate" method is never fired, ever (I was hoping for Authenticate since TryAuthenticate isn't really what I want, they are not trying to log in, just trying to access a secured resource:

```c#
namespace tWorks.Alfa.Modules.ModuleRestApiService
{
    public class AppHost : AppSelfHostBase
    {
        public AppHost() : base("HttpListener Self-Host", typeof(Services.AlfaProService.AlfaProService).Assembly)
        {
        }

        public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {
            Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
                new IAuthProvider[] {
                    new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider(), //HTML Form post of User/Pass
                }
            ));
        }
    }

    public class CustomCredentialsAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
    {
        public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
        {
            return base.TryAuthenticate(authService, userName, password);
        }
        public override object Authenticate(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, Authenticate request)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

When trying this in Fiddler, I just get:

```js
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Set-Cookie: ss-pid=iqGwEavfTzBUeiAOKDcw;path=/;expires=Sun, 07 Feb 2038 13:24:02 GMT;HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: ss-id=sPiGKvFkyRvo78yBvqc8;path=/;HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/5,02 NET45 Win32NT/.NET
WWW-Authenticate: credentials realm="/auth/credentials"
Date: Wed, 07 Feb 2018 13:24:02 GMT

0
```

After this, I tried using the GlobalRequestFilters, but I get no action in there either.

```C#
namespace tWorks.Alfa.Modules.ModuleRestApiService
{
    public class AppHost : AppSelfHostBase
    {
        public AppHost() : base("HttpListener Self-Host", typeof(Services.AlfaProService.AlfaProService).Assembly)
        {
        }

        public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {
            this.GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, requestDto) => 
            {
                // BREAKPOINT NEVER HIT
                string authToken = req.GetHeader("AuthToken");
                res.ReturnAuthRequired();
            });
        }
    }
```

And in Fiddler I see this:

```js
HTTP/1.1 500 No registered Auth Providers found matching any provider
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/5,02 NET45 Win32NT/.NET
Date: Wed, 07 Feb 2018 13:27:09 GMT

71
{"ResponseStatus":{"ErrorCode":"Exception","Message":"No registered Auth Providers found matching any provider"}}
0
```

What do I do?

**UPDATE**
This is the RAW HTTP POST call:

```c#
POST http://192.168.0.147:8080/alfaconnect/login/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.147:8080
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 38
AuthToken: abcdefgh
DeviceUUID: 123asd123

{"Username":"Ted","Password":"String"}
```

Here is the test-request I want to protect and my custom authentication logic to be executed before allowing this method to run. **Don't mind that it's called "Login", it's just a dummy method really**, I want to test to protect and see so my custom code is executed.

```c#
    [Authenticate]
    [Route("/login")]
    public class Login: IReturn<LoginResponse>
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public class LoginResponse
    {
        public string Result { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What URL are you trying to authenticate against? if you’re using a CredentialsAuthProvider it should be /auth/credentials. If you’re still having issues please include the Raw HTTP Request of the Authenticate request (with any confidential info replaced with xxxx)

Comment: Ehm, im not following. In this case, I just want to all calls to requests decorated with [Authenticate] to be validated against my custom logic, in this case, id like to fetch a session object based on the auth token, and see if its OK. SSo, the auth/credentials is irrelevant to me ;-) I'll post the raw request above.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, the `[Authenticate]` attribute is to ensure only Authenticated Users that was authenticated with a AuthProvider can access the Service. But it's added to your own login Request? Which causes many issues a) `[Authenticate]` should never be on a login Service as it will deny access to users who want to login, b) If you're using your own Login Service you're not using ServiceStack AuthProvider so you shouldn't be using `[Authenticate]` also it's recommended for Filter Attributes to be on Service impls so there's no added deps/coupling to ServiceModel.dll.

Comment: If you want to use your own login Service instead of ServiceStack's then you should just remove the `[Authenticate]` attribute and `AuthFeature` since you're just using your own.

Comment: Hey =)
1) As I noted above: the "Login" method is just a dummy method, it could be called MyDummyMethod, so I am aware that the login method cannot be protected. Right now I just wanna test to see if my custom auth code is executed, which it is not.

Comment: 2) I do not want to implement a check for logged in status in each and every method, Id like to have one method that is executed automatically for all those decorated with the Authenticate attribute. As I read it, that should be possible? Thats the point with creating your own CredentialsAuthProvider implementation and overriding Authenticate?

Comment: It's not being called because you're not Authenticating, you're instead trying to call a Service before you've authenticated. You [need to Authenticate](http://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#authenticating-with-net-service-clients) in order for your Custom AuthProvider to get called which sets up an [Authenticated UserSession](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions) that will then allow access to Services protected with `[Authenticate]` attribute. The path to authenticate for CredentialsAuthProvider is `/auth/credentials` which can call with `?Username=xxx&Password=xxx`

Comment: I removed the [Authenticate] attribute, and then the global request filter was executed, at least. But Id really prefer if I could decorate with Authenticate and use the Authenticate metohod in the CredentialsAuthProvider to check if authenticated?

Comment: Yes, its before authentication, but I want my code to determine if they are authenticated or not. So, the method "Authenticate" in the CredentialsAuthProvider should be called? OR...?

Comment: Don't use `[Authenticate]` which will return an 401 Unauthorized response if they're not Authenticated. To check if they're authenticated you'll need to either [check they have a UserSession](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#accessing-typed-session) with `req.SessionAs<AuthUserSession>()` or `req.GetSession()` then check the `.IsAuthenticated` property on the Session or if you have v5 ServiceStack you can use the `req.IsAuthenticated()` helper.

Comment: Thanks for input! But, i have to ask: What is the point with using the first approach above, implementing the CredentialsAuthProvider?

Comment: That's how you authenticate the user with Username/Password credentials. Please go through the different [Authentication-enabled Live Demos](http://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#live-demos).

Comment: Thanks =) I have read all those documents like 25 times, and I dont get it, it seems. If overriding the CredentialsAuthProvider is how you authenticate the user, you mean that is only for creating a session (so, when they are logging in) but not checking if they are already logged in? So, in my case I want to check my own database if the request 1) has an authtoken, 2) if that auth token exists in my database. I do not want to use it to do the actual login.

Comment: On the page, they talk about overriding TryAuthenticate, but never override the Authenticate method, _public override object Authenticate(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, Authenticate request)_

Comment: The docs show a minimal example for implementing a Custom Credentials AuthProvider. My previous comment shows how to check if they’re Authenticated (I.e have an Authenticated User Session), which they can only have after they Authenticate. The AuthProvider is only used for Authenticating (i.e. calling /auth/credentials), I.e to setup the Authenticated Session, it’s not used for checking if they’re Authenticated.

Comment: Alright, that explains it - its only used for when trying to create a session, "when logging in", not anything else. That wasnt clear to me at all.